# Can not get file exist exception after Corda 1.0

Tags: corda

previously in M14, when I upload one document which already exist in the system, the upload function will return one file exist exception. But after upgrade to V1.0, that exception never returned, even the returned hash code is the same as previously one. Does anyone encounter this issue and how to fix that?

I think below core code's function didn't return the exception which is expected.

@Throws(FileAlreadyExistsException::class, IOException::class)
fun importAttachment(jar: InputStream): AttachmentId

Answer (score 1):

This has been changed for V1 as you have noticed. Now, if the attachment is uploaded again, it just returns the hash with no information leakage if that attachment has already been uploaded. You can see the new code in `NodeAttachmentService.kt` - https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/8a5bbe7cf8da9139c647f5256e58bd3a00d4949e/node/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/node/services/persistence/NodeAttachmentService.kt#L175 (master version as of today).

**Update:** After a short discussion with the dev team, we are going to treat this as a bug and raise a ticket for it to be fixed. And I deleted my footnote (viewable in the s/o history)

Comment: I'm just getting this PR into the repo : https://github.com/corda/corda/pull/2053 but you can probably just take the change and put it in your local version if you are compiling locally.

Comment: Do we have any idea about which release will include this new change? Thanks.

Comment: Yes - although the fix was simple, it looks as if the platform has moved on a bit and some tests actually insert duplicate attachments. I'm working on fixing those today....

Comment: So I have updated the PR. It will probably go through a few minor updates before it gets into master but the good news is that it does what it says it does now and all the unit tests pass, so this patch should be good enough for your purposes.

Comment: Could this change be included in next release?

Comment: It just needs a peer review from one of the other developers and it'll be added to the master branch. I'm not sure if it's going to make it into release 2 though as that's been through a fair amount of testing so far - but I'll ask the release team to see it can. Regardless, it will be on master and you can also just apply the patch to a local version as well.

Comment: It's made it into master... Unfortunately the cut off for release 2 was a few days ago so it didn't make it into that formal release, but if you are running against master (i.e. a snapshot) then you can get this modification now. Or, you can cherry pick the change against whatever release you are running against and make any necessary backporting changes (the logger for example).